# viewDidLayoutSubviews troubles on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm writing an app in iOS 8/Swift and have a view and a `UICollectionView` on the screen (screen shot below). Although I'm using auto layout to make sure they're centered, I'm also tapping into `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to make 7 labels that exist inside of my view become spread out across the entire page (and manually doing the layout).

To be more specific, what I'm doing is trying to get the columns in my uicollectionview to be divided by 7 (spread out across 7 columns to represent each day of the week in a calendar), and then make the labels inside of the view divided by 7 as well so they match up with the columns to show what day of the week it is. I want column headers like a calendar, basically.

This works well the first time. You can see it here:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()    
    var labelWidth = (self.view.frame.size.width / 7.0) // view.frame? view.bounds?
    var labelIndex: CGFloat = 0
    var dayHeaders: [UILabel] = [lblSunday, lblMonday, lblTuesday, lblWednesday, lblThursday, lblFriday, lblSaturday]

    //Iterate through each label (day of the week) and change its x position accordingly
    for dayHeader in dayHeaders
    {
        //Loop through each label of the week, and incrementally make it's x position further to the right so it spreads out across each column in my uicollection
        (dayHeader as UILabel).frame = CGRectMake(labelWidth * labelIndex, 0, labelWidth, weekHeaderViews.frame.height);

        //Update the index responsible for helping to change a label's x position
        labelIndex++
    }

    self.view.setNeedsLayout() //these didn't work btw
    self.view.layoutSubviews() //these didn't help btw
}
```

Notice how the columns for each day of the week are lined up with the cells in the `UICollectionView`?

But once I rotate the page, then rotate it back, it never looks the same. The width of the view is somehow different and the labels aren't spaced out the same. No matter how many times I rotate it back and forth, it's permanently spaced out wrong now until I close the app.

What do you think is happening and what could I do to address this? Should I just try moving everything to auto layout and adding constraints, or is there a simpler solution here?